# Manipulate data returned from db call and then assign to template var

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I'm new to smarty and prestashop. I'm building a quick, dirty module that pulls out cms pages with a particular category:

```
$result = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * 
FROM ps_cms_lang
INNER JOIN ps_cms ON ps_cms_lang.id_cms = ps_cms.id_cms
WHERE ps_cms.id_cms_category =2
AND id_lang =1
LIMIT 0 , 30');

$smarty->assign('news', $result);
```

So far this is all working dandy. Thing is I want to format some of this data before I assign it to the template variable (news). How do I do this? 6 fields are returned in the $result variable. How do I get at them and do what I need (which is essentially just truncating some of the text in the description field that is returned) to do and then package them back up for the assign?

Answer (score 0):

You may use $result as array, for example: $result['id_cms'].